# installing CDO in cygwin environoment

Tags: cygwin, cdo-climate

how i can install CDO? 
i am getting this error
./cdo.exe
C:/Users/Ahmad/Downloads/cdo/cdo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygp
roj-13.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Reards

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please describe the steps you are following?

Comment: As of 2020, if you are on windows 10, it is far far easier these days to simply install the linux sub-system. Then you can have full ubuntu, up-to-date without the need for cygwin or an unstable wineserver.  Then it is as simple as sudo apt-get install cdo

Comment: you should follow this procedure https://www.isimip.org/protocol/preparing-simulation-files/cdo-help/

Answer (score 1):

It seems the package was built and linked versus `libproj13`.
You can find that asking the Cygwin project server which package contains a file called `cygproj-13.dll`

```
$ cygcheck -p cygproj-13.dll
Found 3 matches for cygproj-13.dll
libproj13-5.0.1-1 - libproj13: The PROJ Cartographic Projections Software
libproj13-5.1.0-1 - libproj13: The PROJ Cartographic Projections Software
libproj13-5.2.0-1 - libproj13: The PROJ Cartographic Projections Software
```

so you need to install the `libproj13` with Cygwin `setup`.